# current date parameter is not updating from query in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a query (named as query1) as follows:
[image]

and current date Paramter:

[image]

now the problem is that, parameter is not updating, I tried changing the both (query1 and currentdate parameter) to date first, the Paramter was not updating, then I tried changing both to Text, still the Paramter is not updating.

what mistake am I doing?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. `Current Value` is static once entered/selected. What are you trying to do?

Comment: yea the current value is static, but it still needs. it doesn't accept empty current value. I have to refresh report based on current Date.

Comment: Then just use what you have in Query1. No need to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting Query1 to a list.  Not 100% sure this will work as I don't have PQ in front of me but at times when I've tried to have a parameter built off a query I've had to have the query formatted as a list.